# Download .rar attachment failure from draft message

Tags: gmail, security, gmail-attachments

I have this mail draft in my Gmail like for 6-7 years. This draft has an attachment of .rar file which contains a small project that I did when I was senior in college.

I want to send this mail to myself, or just download the attached file from the draft. However, Gmail doesn't let me do that. It pops an error message for either case, saying:

> For security reasons, Gmail does not allow you to use this type of
>   file as it violates Google policy for executables and archives.

Is there a way to get the attachment?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would configure the account to enable IMAP so that you can download messages (with their attachments) from Gmail using an email program such as Thunderbird, Apple Mail or Microsoft Outlook.

Using a mail client with IMAP gives you an alternate method to access mail messages; GMail *labels*, *Drafts* and *Sent Messages* will appear as folders in the email program.

Describing how to configure GMail with IMAP would be too broad an issue to answer here but Google have lots of good info on [how to use Gmail with IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/topic/3398031?hl=en&vid=1-635803294113345466-650198010).

Comment: Will I be able to see my draft mails if I use such mail client?

Comment: @guneykayim I've just updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I succeeded using mail app in iPhone just mail changing the from address to my iCloud address.

Comment: @guneykayim That was very quick. I was just going to warn you not to accept my answer until you'd verified that it worked. Glad to have helped.